# Do you know a way to download the audio from Google and Microsoft Text-to-Speech?

Tags: windows, macos, ubuntu, google-chrome

do you know a way to download the audio from Google and Microsoft Text-to-Speech and I know there is AudioTTS but it sucks and it does not work if you know another way to download it or if you know other websites where I can download Text-to-Speech Ai that would also be good I thank you already thank you nice

Answer (score 1):

You can use software like [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) and select STEREO MIX as your input device. That will record whatever is going out of the speakers.